# Express router : Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I know there are lot of questions in SO but none of them gave me a solution

**routes/authentication/index.js**

```
import { Router } from 'express'

const router = Router();

router.get('/', (_req, _res) => console.log("Works"))

// module.exports = router                    <-- this works
export default router                      // <-- this doesn't
```

**constants.js**

```
const ROUTES = {
    'AUTHENTICATION' : require('../routes/authentication')
}

export default ROUTES
```

and using it in app.js as

```
import express from 'express'
import connectDatabase from './connectDb';
import ROUTES from './constants';
const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
}
connectDatabase()

app.get('/', (_req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world")
})

app.use('/auth', ROUTES.AUTHENTICATION)

export default app;
```

Now with `module.exports = router` works but `export default router` throws an error

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

I tried finding the cause for the problem but couldn't.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You `require` the router file in `constants.js`, hence `module.exports` works.

Comment: @Vishnudev got it . It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `require` the router file in `constants.js`, hence `module.exports` works.

For `export default router` to work, you need to import it.